# Is there a way to get a Set/Array of minutes and hours in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uipickerview

I'm trying to populate my picker view with minutes and hours in the simplest way possible. I'm implementing a custom picker so using `UIDatePicker` with it's mode set to `UIDatePickerModeTime` is out of the question.

Is there a function available in iOS to retrieve the data set or do I just have to initialise the array with hardcoded values from `0-12` (12 hour system) and `0-60` for the hours and minutes respectively with say a for loop?

I'm currently populating the array like so:

```
#pragma mark - Lazy Loading
-(NSArray *)hourValues{
    if(!_hourValues){
        NSMutableArray *hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            [hours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }
        _hourValues = hours;
    }
    return _hourValues;
}
-(NSArray *)minuteValues{
    if(!_minuteValues){
        NSMutableArray *minutes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
            [minutes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }
        _minuteValues = minutes;
    }
    return _minuteValues;
}
-(NSArray *)amPmValues{
    if(!_amPmValues){
        _amPmValues = @[@"am", @"pm"];
    }
    return _amPmValues;
}
```

I don't like the hardcoded values.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
hours = [NSDate NS12HourSetArray];
minutes = [NSDate NS60MinuteArray];
```

Comment: Maybe with `NSDateComponents/NSCalendar` & `maximumRangeOfUnit:`, but still, it would just give you the 60/etc.

Comment: @Larme Hey, thanks for commenting. How would that work then?

Comment: **Note**: You should either initialise from 1-12 or 0-11; similarly 0-59 or 1-60. Initialising 0-12 and 0-60 gives you too many minutes and hours. ;)

Comment: **Counter Note:** That depends on how you use the comparison operator. ;) @IanMacDonald

Answer (score 3):

I think you have 3 options:

- Write a script/automate creating textual data and load it at runtime, you can easily do that in python/bash and plist.
- do it manually using the good old for loop. I recommend that.
- or You can create an index set from whatever range you want using `NSIndexSet` and `NSRange` objects respectively.

for example:

```
NSIndexSet *minutesIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 60)];
```

Then you ether make your UI load form the index set directly, or again enumerate the index set and fill an array with its indexes.

In both ways what you are ultimately doing is iterating through a loop to fill your arrays manually. the only one that does only the load is the first one.

Comment: I see, so there are no `NSDate/NSDateComponents/NSCalendar` functions readily available that have a set for this purpose like they do with the `[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]`, for example?

Comment: I'm not aware of any API like that, and I can't see a reason for apple to provide one, since most of data objects depend on calculations rather than data sets.

Comment: just like how apple have provided data sets like so: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-SW5 I thought there might have been a way to retrieve `date` datasets

Comment: strings and characters aren't mathematically related, so having data sets makes sense, dates are mathematically related to each other so having a collection of them is lazy programming at best, and a bad practice most likely.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean by mathematically related. Why is it lazy programming? I would have thought it was more of a convenience method. I have been following the second approach so far. Thank you for your input, I think I'll go down the category class route as suggested by the other poster to make things look more neater and more hidden away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in methods that you can call like this. Personally, I don't really see an issue with hard-coding things like "the number of minutes in an hour" because it's well-defined and you can be relatively sure that it won't ever change. You could hide it from yourself a little bit by making a category on `NSDate` if that's where you expect the API to exist.

```
@interface NSDate (ConvenientArrays)
+ (NSArray *)minutesInAnHourArray;
+ (NSArray *)hourRepresentationsPerDay:(BOOL)use24Hour;
@end

@implementation NSDate (ConvenientArrays)
+ (NSArray *)minutesInAnHourArray {
  return @[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
           10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
           20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
           30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
           40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
           50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59];
}
+ (NSArray *)hourRepresentationsPerDay:(BOOL)use24Hour {
  if (use24Hour) {
    return @[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
             10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
             20, 21, 22, 23];
  }
  return @[     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
           10, 11, 12];
}
@end
```

Comment: Up until now I have been hard coding it with a for loop. You're right, they are well defined. Nice touch with the category approach, that approach skipped my mind and will most certainly make things a little neater. I will create a category for the sake of tidiness. Out of curiosity, in which class would you have the API exist if not in the `NSDate` class. `NSCalender`, `NSDateComponents` or perhaps in another class?

Comment: That depends on your usage. If you're using it for displaying to a human, you might consider putting it in `NSDateFormatter`. I wrote `hourRepresentationsPerDay:` in this way so that it returns `0-23` for 24-hour and `1-12` for 12-hour display. It's up to you, though. Put it wherever makes sense to you.